# Finding a type by namespace and name in UWP .NET Native builds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, .net-core, .net-native

I'm building a library at work that lets us build Unity3D projects for a variety of different platforms. There is a core library that implements generic functions and then each specific platform is implemented in a separate DLL, serving as a plugin. One of those platforms is the Microsoft HoloLens.

Typically, a Unity3D application is a Mono app with a large amount of hackery built in based on Unity-the-company's inability to keep up with the times on .NET versions. But on the HoloLens, the only type of applications you can run are UWP apps. You get the choice to run them as .NET Core or .NET Native apps.

When I run the project in Debug or Release build (i.e. .NET Core mode), then I can find my plugins via the following (simplified) Linq query (this happens on startup, not per-frame, so the performance implications of using a Linq query over iterating manually are negligible).

```
(from file in await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFilesAsync()
where file.Name.EndsWith(".dll") || file.Name.EndsWith(".exe")
let asmName = new AssemblyName(file.DisplayName)
let asm = Assembly.Load(name)
let t = asm?.GetType("MyCompany.MyProject.MyClass")
where t != null
select t).FirstOrDefault();
```

But when I run in Master mode (i.e. .NET Native), this same code fails to find the type of interest.

`Type.GetType` does not find the type, either.

Comment: so, i would drop from linq to a foreach and find out if `asm` is returned. If it is, check `asm.GetExportedTypes()` to see if your class is there.

Also, if you want to use `Type.GetType`, use `typeof(T).AssemblyQualifiedName`

Comment: I already know `asm` is not always returned. You don't need to "drop to a foreach" to find that out, you can debug iterate over Linq queries. This isn't the actual query, it's just a simplified version that demonstrates the idea. Also, I don't need `Type.GetType` to work. I don't have the type `T` to be able to call `typeof(T)` because, as I said, this is a plugin architecture. I absolutely need to go from a string type-name to a reflected type, because the type-name is a value in a configuration file.

Comment: Just use a qualified string

Comment: This seems to work, but it is not a very good solution. I provide an enumeration of all supported platforms, which can be chosen from within the Unity editor. Having to specify the qualified name would require that keep track of a list of platforms *and* the assemblies in which they are implemented, instead of just the platforms.

Comment: if you already store `"MyCompany.MyProject.MyClass"` somewhere, why not store `MyCompany.MyProject.MyClass, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcd` instead, and then for UI purposes just dropout assembly name?